# How does this graph show 3000 In the Money June 19 $130 puts traded?

Tags: finance

[image]

Does this graph imply [3000 ITM 6/19 $130 puts traded](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/gvdv3s/tif_leaked_info/fso0udw/)? How? I don't see "3000" or "puts" or "6/19".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a chart of the underlying stock. It does not show anything about options.